# How to parse AJAX array into specific HTML div classes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I currently have a working AJAX request that sends a request to my PHP file and echos the result to the HTML. I am able to create an alert that shows the array of data. How do I parse the data and insert each one specifically into the div classes? I know you might be thinking "just use a table or a list" My actual code is much more structured, the data must be inserted into the specific divs.
**Script**

```
    $(function(){
        $(".task-listing").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'php/task-info-get.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'pid=' + $(this).attr("id"),
            success: function (response) {
                 alert(response);
            }
        })
    });
    });
```

**HTML div I want Data in**

```
<div class="data">
  <div class="task_date"></div>
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div class="description"></div>
  <div class="location"></div>
  <div class="startdate"></div>
  <div class="tasktime"></div>
  <div class="price"></div>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
include 'sqlconnection.php';
$conn = OpenCon();

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT task_date,title,description,location,price,startdate,tasktime FROM tasks WHERE pid='.$_POST['pid']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($task_date,$title,$description,$location,$price,$startdate,$tasktime);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $output[]=array($task_date,$title,$description,$location,$price,$startdate,$tasktime);
}
$json=json_encode($output);

echo $json;
$stmt->close();
CloseCon($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Are you only returning one row of data?

Comment: per click of the listing, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would modify your PHP to return an associative array, with the keys being the class of the relevant `div` you want the data to go into:

```
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $output[]=array(
        'task_date' => $task_date,
        'title' => $title,
        'description' => $description,
        'location' => $location,
        'price' => $price,
        'startdate' => $startdate,
        'tasktime' => $tasktime
    );
}
```

Then in your JS you can simply use the keys of the response to fill the divs:

```
success: function (response) {
    Object.keys(response[0]).map(k => $('.' + k).text(response[0][k]));
}
```

Here's a snippet demonstrating the code (using a normal rather than arrow function):

```js
let response = [{
  task_date: "2020-02-26 17:56:15",
  title: "cccccccccccccc",
  description: "cccccccccccccc",
  location: "Remote",
  price: 44,
  startdate: "2020-02-14",
  tasktime: "00:03:33"
}]

Object.keys(response[0]).map(function(k) {
  $('.' + k).text(response[0][k]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data">
  <div class="task_date"></div>
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div class="description"></div>
  <div class="location"></div>
  <div class="startdate"></div>
  <div class="tasktime"></div>
  <div class="price"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: when i change my prepared statement to what you suggested, the alert just says [object Object], there is no array of data

Comment: Because it's Object in js now, you can use it to access exact key.

Comment: ok, im trying to understand lol. i am really new to JS, ajax and PHP. must I substitute the 'k' for a div or key? do i put my class name in the '.'? if you could just show an example of how to do one object in the array that would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: @BrettMalone you can use that code directly in your .ajax `success` function. See my edit

Comment: @BrettMalone it will use the keys from the object which is now being returned (in place of your array) to select the `div` to be filled in by its class (`$('.'+k)`) and it will use the value from the object (`response[k]`) to fill in the `div`.

Comment: @BrettMalone note you may need to use `Object.keys(response[0])`

Comment: with both versions of Object.keys(response[0]) and Object.keys(response) no output occurred.

Comment: @BrettMalone what do you get if you `console.log(response)`?

Comment: @BrettMalone note you won't see any output but the contents of the divs should be updated.

Comment: task_date: "2020-02-26 17:56:15"
title: "cccccccccccccc"
description: "cccccccccccccc"
location: "Remote"
price: 44
startdate: "2020-02-14"
tasktime: "00:03:33" I get the full array.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console when you get a response from the ajax call? Are you using internet explorer?

Comment: @BrettMalone see my edit. I've added a snippet demonstrating the code.

Comment: @BrettMalone note you do need `response[0]` in both locations

Comment: nick, youre a god my man. i cant thank you enough... saving me so much time. the object.keys part in the snippet code was what did it. its slightly different than the one you posted earlier. can i donate?

Comment: @BrettMalone accepting the answer is as much as is required. I'm glad it's working for you.

Comment: please, i insist. you spent a lot of time helping me, you deserve something

Comment: Seriously, it's no problem, I do this for fun.

Answer (score 0):

If the response is always an array with full enough content (length = 7) & in order as childs in div.data tag, you can just do this with Jquery:

```
const responses = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
$('.data').children().each((index, child) => {
    $(child).text(responses[index])
});
```

E.g: https://jsbin.com/cikacohalu/edit?html,js,output

For more complicated html structure, use direct selector to set their content:

```
$('.data .task_date').text(response[0]);
$('.data .title').text(response[1]);
$('.data .description').text(response[2]);
$('.data .location').text(response[3]);
$('.data .startdate').text(response[4]);
$('.data .tasktime').text(response[5]);
$('.data .price').text(response[6]);
```

I would recommend the @Nick's answer, that you have exact key name for each field from PHP backend to client.

Comment: isnt there some way to do... document.getElementByClassName("title").innerHTML = //something something// for each item in the array?

Comment: Yeah, absolutely can. You don't want to use jQuery or something?

Comment: no, i want to be able to add them specifically into the div i want. My real html is a lot more complicated, with a lot of divs inside divs for structure and styling. I just did it simple like this so that I can apply it to my real code

Comment: Then you must have data structured in response array, can you post an example of response?

Comment: 2020-02-27 23:55:10,help me out,i need someone to help me out(description),Local,25,2020-02-27,00:12:30

Comment: when i put that in, it did the entire array in the first div

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this,

```
  $(function(){
        $(".task-listing").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'php/task-info-get.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: 'pid=' + $(this).attr("id"),
                success: function (response) {
                    var jsonres=JSON.parse(result);
                    htmlconts='';
                    for (i in jsonres) {
                        htmlconts+='<div class="data">\
                            <div class="task_date">'+jsonres[i][0]+'</div>\
                            <div class="title">'+jsonres[i][1]+'</div>\
                            <div class="description">'+jsonres[i][2]+'</div>\
                            <div class="location">'+jsonres[i][3]+'</div>\
                            <div class="startdate">'+jsonres[i][4]+'</div>\
                            <div class="tasktime">'+jsonres[i][5]+'</div>\
                            <div class="price">'+jsonres[i][6]+'</div>\
                        </div>';
                    }
                    $("body").append(htmlconts);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

I have appended the final contents in `body` tag. you may use the parent of `class='data'`.

Comment: if i have divs inside other divs it wont work. id like to avoid appending the entire block if possible because it is much more structured than this. is it possible to do... document.getElementByClassName("title").innerHTML = //something something// for each item in the array?

Comment: yes, you can use like `document.getElementsByClassName("title")[0].innerText=+jsonres[i][1];`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share your response if possible?

Is it a single object?

if single object then it's not good to assume and iterate through a loop to get specific key-value based on an index of an array. eg. task_date is at 2 positions in an array.

parse your ajax response first eg. var jsonres=JSON.parse(result);
append your value by jquery selecter $(".task_date").html(data);